# Minecraft- Cannot Connect To CraftBukkit-Spigot Server 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I try to connect to my Minecraft **Craftbukkit-Spigot** Server but it will not connect! I can join with "*localhost*" but not with my IP I get from *www.whatsmyip.com* ... I **portfowarded** and the **console has no errors** yet I am unable to join **my firewall has the ports allowed** same with java/minecraft but it will not let me join! How can I fix this? Version 1.8

Comment: Could you state the port-forwarding settings you've entered into your router?

Answer (score 2):

Very few - if any - consumer routers will allow you to connect to an internal IP using your public IP from within the network.  The router doesn't loop-back requests to your public IP.

What you need to do in order to test your setup properly is to actually connect to the server from the "outside world".  This means getting a friend to test, tethering your computer (but not the server) to a smart phone, or hopping on an open wifi connection.  VPNs and proxies would also work.

Comment: Portforwarding is done on your modem. The only thing I can think of is that his configuration was incorrect, which was my case for... 2 years.

Comment: No, port-forwarding is done on whichever device provides the NAT functionality, which is almost always the router.  The modem only provides the interface between the ethernet LAN and the connection to the ISP.  However, these days a high-speed internet modem often also contains a router.

Comment: Sorry; I got the two mixed up. (The router is where you do your port-forwarding; connected to the ISP, while your modem is part of your computer) | Point is @MBraedley, he may has done things correct, but configured it wrongly. For example, had a translated port inputted when it's not needed as it messes up the connections and ends up blocking it for not fitting the ports inputted to the router.